# Can you control browser back button using JSF faces-config navigation

Tags: jsf, back-button

Can you control browser back button using JSF faces-config navigation? When the back button is pressed on browser would like to use navigation like the following to control what page to display:

```
 <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/pageThree.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>back</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/pageOne.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. It's already not possible with HTML/JS, so JSF can't do much for you here.

Your best bet is to conditionally display the content of pageTwo.xhtml in pageOne.xhtml, based on some JS/ajax condition. This way there's no GET request on pageTwo.xhtml in the browser history.

Here's a basic kickoff example with plain JS:

```
<div id="one">
   <h1>Page one</h1>
   <p><a href="#" onclick="showPageTwo()">Go to page two</a></p>
</div>
<div id="two" style="display: none;">
   <h1>Page two</h1>
   <p><a href="pageThree.xhtml">Go to page three</a></p>
</div>
```

with

```
<script>
    function showPageTwo() {
        document.getElementById("one").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("two").style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

This is also easy with JSF 2.0 ajax and the `rendered` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution : [dojo.back](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/back) and [jqueryTools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/history.html)